# Java getSystemJavaCompiler from JDK

Tags: compilation, java

I am using `ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();`, but it is returning `null` because my JDK isn't in my PATH (and I can't put it there). How would I make getSystemJavaCompiler() use my JDK?

Comment: What has PATH got to do with it? The question is whether tools.jar is in your *class*path.

Comment: @bmargulies By tools.jar do you mean "<JDK_ROOT>/lib/tools.jar"? Because I thought that contained `sun.tools.javac.*` (the Deprecated way)

Comment: That is the only implementation in town. The approved API you are calling is mapped to it -- if and only if it is in the classpath.

Comment: @bmargulies I added it to the class path `-classpath "c:/bin/jdk/lib/tools.jar"`, but getSystemJavaCompiler() still returns null.

Comment: Try a more direct experiment and report the result of `Class.getResource("sun/tools/javac/Main.class");`

Comment: BTW - there seems to be no functional difference between this thread and your [earlier thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616886/java-compiler-api-nullpointerexception).  Did I miss something?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm not using `sun.tools.javac.Main` because it's deprecated.

Comment: @AndrewThompson `Class.class.getResource("sun/tools/javac/Main.class");` returns null;

But `System.getProperty("java.class.path")` does contain the path to tools.jar

Comment: @LanguagesNamedAfterCofee  Note that my name has a space in it.  It is best to copy/paste such things.